# Display value of returned var into render react native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am learning react native and i really don't understand why i can't display my returned var **username** into my render's **View**

i tried several thing but no one worked

```
Read() {

    var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    var username= snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().profile_picture
      alert(username);
      this.setState({username})
      // How to display username into my return
    });
  }

render() {
    const {username} = this.state

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Avatar style={styles.photo}
        size="small"
        rounded
        source={{uri: "#"}}
        onPress={() => this.Read()}
        activeOpacity={0.7}
      />
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
        {username} //display nothing 
      </Text>
      <View >
```

I put an alert into Read() to check if i got the value i wanted so i know that the var username store the value that i wanted to display into my view.

**Console log :** 
[log screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prAUy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in Syntax, you are not updating the state correct.

Wrong syntax: **this.setState(username)**

Correct syntax: **this.setState({ username })**

Here is the problem:

> const username = snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().profile_picture;

Try to change this line of code like this: **const username = snapshot.val()**

Let me know if username is presented.

Comment: I did it before but it steel display nothing i will edit my post with the good syntax sorry

Comment: Hi @DorianGrn you need then to console.log(username) before alert(username) line of code. To check does you get value before updating the state. 
Let me know what happen.

Comment: I belive the problem is in this line of code: var username = snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().profile_picture;
Console.log(username) after that line of code.

Comment: hi it print a warning :Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Comment: i added a screen of the console into my post @Nikola trajkovic

Comment: Nothing is displayed with const username = snapshot.val() and const username = snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().profile_picture;
I don't understand what's going on @Nikola trajkovic

Comment: remove .database() from here return firebase
      .database()
      .ref("/users/" + userId)
      .once("value")

Comment: but `<Text style={styles.paragraph}>
        {username}

      </Text> `don't display the var : i need to press on the Avatar : 
`onPress={() => this.Read()}`
Then it display the data xD
Why ?

Answer (score 0):

[`this.setState()` in React takes an object that describes the state keys to update](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

We can use the shorthand `{username}` to create an object of the form `{username: username}`, so:

```
class Component {
  Read() {
    var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    return firebase
      .database()
      .ref("/users/" + userId)
      .once("value")
      .then((snapshot) => {
        var username = snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().profile_picture;
        alert(username);
        this.setState({username});  // <-- this has changed
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { username } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Avatar
          style={styles.photo}
          size="small"
          rounded
          source={{ uri: "#" }}
          onPress={() => this.Read()}
          activeOpacity={0.7}
        />
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{username}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, i already tried this way but it steel display nothing :/

Comment: I edited my post with corect syntax and added a screen of my log @AKX Thanks for your time

Comment: @DorianGrn Ah, yeah. Fixed. The `.then()` callback must also be an arrow function to capture `this` properly. Try the edited version?

Comment: Nothing is display to, i really don't get it i spent tons of hour on it
Any other idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You tried to use the `this` object which refers to your component into a traditional function, it does not bind the context of the component (getting an error like *`setState` is not a function*) because `setState` is not available in the context of your function, so uses an arrow function inside your `Read` function like this:

```
Read() {
    var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    return firebase
      .database()
      .ref("/users/" + userId)
      .once("value")
      .then((snapshot) => {
        const username = snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().profile_picture;
        this.setState({ username : username });
        // You can use shorthanded syntax if you want 
        // this.setState({ username });
      });
 }
```

Comment: I also tried it before posting my post and it doesn't work, nothing is displayed to :(